# Client and Service and Database with safe interaction

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have a client application that talks to a service over WCF. The client and the service both run on the same machine.The service can talk to a database every X minutes. The client only talks to the database when a user presses a button. It is a requirement that the client and service not talk to the database at the same time as sync issues can then occur with data.
My proposed solution is that when the user presses the button on the client application that the client stops the service, The client application can then safely makes the database update and finally restarts the service. This will be done via the System.ServiceProcess.dll in c#.

Is this the best way to do this ?

Comment: Exactly what kind of sync issues are you trying to mitigate against? Stopping the service to perform a client operation seems drastic. Why not have the service handle all DB calls and return data to the client?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli the service has "old" settings from the database and will upload results but now the settings will of changed as the client has sent up new settings. its the same analogy as modifying settings in an application and you must restart the app for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: @spaceghostali My first thoughts were the same as yours in that it seems excessive but when you think about it we do the same when we update any allication settings. I.e reboot the app for the new settings to take effect.